# Class init failed in newInstance call

Tags: android-ndk

I am  continuously facing a situation of which I have no idea. I am tried to test one method that I have implemented in C++. I got an error, a Class init failed when calling newInstance .
It further states that cannot load library:reloc_library[1311]:33 cannot locate '*Z13trainFacePKcS0*'...  and suddenly it crashes and throw exception. It gives the same error. I will appreciate any help.
Regards,
Adonis.

Answer (score 0):

You have loaded a library like this in the class which gets loaded during class initialization.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("gamescript");
}
```

From your error you have posted, it seems the library cannot be located which means, it either is not present in the apk file or it is not inside the libs folder.

Comment: the library is present in the libs folder

Comment: Another possible reason, the library is using a shared library that is not loaded before it.

Comment: According elf -d 0x00000001 (NEEDED)  Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)Shared library: [libstdc++.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libfaceRec.so]